# How can JavaScript functions work in php loop?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

How can javascript work in php loop? below is my sample codes, I need to click button and then take the value from name textbox based on the loop button I click.

```
<?php
for($count=0;$count<=4;$count++)
{
echo"
<form action=\"\" method=\"POST\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\" onSubmit=\"return false;\">
<input id=\"name\" type=\"text\" name=\"name\">
<input type=\"button\" name=\"send\" id=\"but_upload\" value=\">\">
";
?>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#but_upload").click(function(){
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('name', document.getElementById('name').value);
        
        if ($('#name').val()) {
        $('#name').val('');
        }
    });
});
</script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Please anyone can help me

Comment: you should have a loop to create multiple forms and another loop to create multiple click events instead. Also id must be unique.

Comment: You can add a class to the button and select the `closest` form input with another class to change the value of the target `name` input. Don't select by ids

Comment: Can you please show me the example, I'm not good in javascript but simple example is enough for me. Thank you

Comment: @Dev why are you trying to make multiple scripts with the loop?

Comment: I need to have the comment field on each item posted, where user if he/she needs to comment he/she will click that send button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to do something like this:

```
<?php
for($count=0;$count<=4;$count++)
{
echo"
<form action=\"\" method=\"POST\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\" onSubmit=\"return false;\">
<input class=\"name\" type=\"text\" name=\"name\">
<input type=\"button\" name=\"send\" class=\"but_upload\" value=\">\"></form>
";
}
?>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".but_upload").click(function(event){
        var fd = new FormData();
        var nameEl = event.target.form.querySelector('.name')
        fd.append('name', nameEl.value);
        if (nameEl.value) {
            nameEl.value = '';
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Is it possible to use <button> instead of <input type> there? Thank you

Comment: Yes you can just change the `<input>` to `<button></button>`. Then you don't really need a type.